# if same email id is already used in newsletter a pop should come user already registered?but it is showing pop thank you for subscribtion

Tags: newsletter

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
        jQuery(".news_button").click(function() {
        if (newsletterSubscriberFormDetail.validator.validate())
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data:  jQuery("#newsletter-validate-detail").serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                if(data == 1) {
                jQuery('.news-popup').reveal({
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 200,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    
                });
                jQuery('#newsletter').val('');
                } else {
                jQuery('.news-popup-error').html('<center><img style="padding-top: 10px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/headerlogo.png') ?>" alt="header logo" /></center><a href="javascript:;" class="close"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinurl('images/btn-remove.png'); ?>" /></a><?php echo $this->__('This email has already been registered for our newsletter subscription, please try with another email')?>');
                jQuery('.news-popup-error').reveal({
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 200,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    
                });
                }
                }
            });
        }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leo,you need to customization at  newsletter Module  `SubscriberController.php` at newAction and here you need check mail is alread exits on by using

```
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
if($subscriber->getId())
{
     put your logic 
}
```

Or if you have customer id then you can directly check in newsletter_subscriber table to check if customer id exists or not.

Comment: $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                        ->loadByEmail($email)
                        ->getId();
                if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
                    //Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
     
     echo 'This email address is already assigned to another user.';
                }
Hello amit please help i will change here or in down

Comment: it will reply shortly

Comment: $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    //$session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
     echo '1';
                }
                else {
                    //$session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
     echo '1';

Comment: i am doing it by email id